# How to use core crypto types instead of runtime types?

Tags: subxt

I am trying to use core crypto types instead of runtime types (because I know they are the same):

```rust
#[subxt::subxt(
    runtime_metadata_path = "metadata.scale",
    derive_for_all_types = "Debug"
)]
pub mod runtime {
    #[subxt(substitute_type = "sp_core::sr25519::Signature")]
    use crate::runtime::runtime_types::sp_core::sr25519::Signature;
}
```

but the compiler complains:

```
expected `runtime_types::sp_core::sr25519::Signature`, found `sp_core::sr25519::Signature`
note: `sp_core::sr25519::Signature` and `runtime_types::sp_core::sr25519::Signature` have similar names, but are actually distinct types
`sp_core::sr25519::Signature` is defined in crate `sp_core`
`runtime_types::sp_core::sr25519::Signature` is defined in the current crate
/ #[subxt::subxt( /* ... */ )]
|____________________________^
```

How should the type substitution work? Or do I have to implement type conversion like `Signature(signature.0)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, it looks like you're using quite an old version of Subxt (that syntax for substituting types went away quite a while ago), so I'd recommend updating.

If you're just looking to do some type substitution, then the new syntax is more powerful, and the docs for that can he [found here](https://docs.rs/subxt/latest/subxt/attr.subxt.html#substitute_typepath---with--). One way to do it would be like this:

```rust
#[subxt::subxt(
    runtime_metadata_path = "metadata.scale",
    substitute_type(
        // the type that's generated:
        path = "sp_core::sr25519::Signature",
        // This is the type we swap it for:
        with = "::subxt::utils::Static<::sp_core::sr25519::Signature>"
    )
)]
mod polkadot {}
```

The type we are swapping it for is wrapped in this `Static` wrapper. This is because generated types need to impl `DecodeAsType` and `EncodeAsType` nowadays, which the substrate primitives do not, and the `Static` type impls them and just falls back to using `Decode`/`Encode` impls instead (which they do implement).

That all said, implementing `From` conversions are generally more reliable (since you don't need to swap any types and then assume they the swapped types are actually still valid in place of the old ones). So I'd actually recommend starting with an approach like this, if it works for your use case:

```rust
#[subxt::subxt(
    runtime_metadata_path = "metadata.scale",
    derive_for_all_types = "Debug"
)]
mod runtime {}

impl From<runtime::sp_core::sr25519::Signature> for sp_core::sr25519::Signature {
    fn from(value: runtime::sp_core::sr25519::Signature) -> Self {
        sp_core::sr25519::Signature(value.0)
    }
}
```

This generalises well to other types too, and lets you leave the generated code alone.